# Can an app be written to run on any devices?

Tags: app-store, device, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-devices

I would like to know if it is possible to write apps that can run on any devices.

Comment: as a web application...delivered through a browser...yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about mobile devices, in theory, yes, there are frameworks out there like [Sencha Touch](http://sencha.com) that should be able to run on any device, but often you don't want to have your app look the exact same on every device due to different conventions.